# How to see if a google site is updated

Tags: wordpress, laravel, google-sites

I'm planning to use Google Sites API - Revision Feed in order to check if a google site is updated.(what I mean by google site https://sites.google.com/site/username). Also I may use it in Laravel or WP. Do you have any other platform or way suggestion that will make it easier and more efficient?

Comment: You want to check feed or use want to check the updates done to a particular page ?

Comment: I just want to check if a site is updated recently in last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give a good gadget for that.
"Subscribe to changes for Sites viewers"

I use this on my Google sites and it's really nice.

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/subscribe-to-changes-for-viewers